# How to create an array of 3 floats and name it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been given a task which consists of the 12 sub-assignments and here is the one of this sub-assignment that I struggling with:

*Create an array of 3 floats, and name this array r6. Initialize the array r6 with the values of three var, ables r1, r4, and r5.*

```
//Requirement: Create an array of 3 floats and name this array r6
var r6 = [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ];          

//  Initialize the array r6 with the values of three variables r1, r4 and r5.
r6[1.0] = r1;
r6[2.0] = r4;
r6[3.0] = r5;
```

Is that the right way to do that? Or how can I modify it?

Comment: You should read about array notation.

Comment: Did you search on "javascript create array" before asking this?  Google returns 3.65 million results, many of them on StackOverflow.  Please search before asking duplicate questions.

Comment: @Dave S Hi Dave! yes, I did and found a plenty of them. But I was curious if I'm doing it in right way just because of that. My apologies if it was similar to someone else question, I was asking just for an opinion.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Ok, I'll thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to initialize the variables.

```
const r1 = 1.5;
const r4 = 2.7;
const r5 = 5.8;
```

Then, you assign values inside the array from the variables you initialized earlier:

`const r6 = [r1, r4, r5];`

if you log these:
`console.log(r6); // returns [1.5, 2.7, 5.8]`

Answer (score -1):

You must assign new values as:

```
//  Initialize the array r6 with the values of three variables r1, r4 and r5.
r6[0] = r1; // change 1.0 to r1
r6[1] = r4; // change 2.0 to r2
r6[2] = r5; // change 3.0 to r3
```

Comment: is that right? : var r6 = [ r1, r4, r5 ];  r6[0] = r1; 
r6[1] = r4; 
r6[2] = r5;